# Панель для текста и авторазмер логотипа

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такую штучку, чтоб наполовину над слайдером сидела,а дальше в контент уходила:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и еще авторазмер логотипа вместе со всем сайтом, как сделать?
 Код:

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type:none;
}
header {
 height:40px;
 width:60%;
 margin-left:20%;
 position:fixed;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 z-index:120;
}
header li {
 float: left;
 list-style-type:none;
 border-right: 1px solid #252525;
}
header li a {
 float: left;
 width: 98px;
 height: 12px;
 padding: 14px 7px;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font: normal 62.5% "proxima-nova-alt", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.logo {
 position:absolute;
 left:-200px;
 top:10px;
 width: 160px;
 height: 210px;
 background:url('https://i.imgur.com/YpUfTvW.png') no-repeat;
}
@-webkit-keyframes TMNT {
 0%  { left: 0px; }
 100% { left: -1200px; }
}
a.prev,a.next {
 height:91px;
 position:absolute;
 width:43px;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-30px;
 opacity:0.6;
 text-indent:-99999px;
 cursor:pointer;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms ease-out;
}
a.prev:hover,a.next:hover {
 opacity:1;
}
.prev {
 left:0;
 background: #000 url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JN1IZLtuToI/UUoZnMG3C_I/AAAAAAAAAE8/SEbJ9nqXGnY/s226/sprite.png') no-repeat -200px 25px;
}
.next {
 right:0;
 background: #000 url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JN1IZLtuToI/UUoZnMG3C_I/AAAAAAAAAE8/SEbJ9nqXGnY/s226/sprite.png') no-repeat -167px 25px;
}
.slider {
 height:100vh;
 position: relative;
}
.slide {
 position:absolute;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.slider .slide:target {
 z-index: 100;
}
img {
 max-width:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Туристическая компания Юг-Вояж</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider.css" >
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Туристам</a></li>
      <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li id="slider-1" class="slide">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PcDDGh9C6Uk/UUoRYu8TmGI/AAAAAAAAADk/bVCVnUEott4/s1231/2.jpeg.jpg">
      <a class="prev" href="#slider-4">prev</a>
      <a class="next" href="#slider-2">next</a>
    </li>
    <li id="slider-2" class="slide">
      <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ImESS5vXwTQ/UUoRZtDDdwI/AAAAAAAAAD0/mBlvPxXMuDU/s1231/3.jpeg.jpg">
      <a class="prev" href="#slider-1">prev</a>
      <a class="next" href="#slider-3">next</a>           
    </li>
    <li id="slider-3" class="slide">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-a4HykmTjnLw/UUoRZ9AOzNI/AAAAAAAAAD8/bsVqg8naI2o/s1231/4.jpeg.jpg">
      <a class="prev" href="#slider-2">prev</a>
      <a class="next" href="#slider-4">next</a>           
    </li>
    <li id="slider-4" class="slide">
      <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lmIWz4ADxc0/UUoRaFjdNXI/AAAAAAAAAEI/widPZMMiBVM/s1231/5.jpeg.jpg">
      <a class="prev" href="#slider-3">prev</a>
      <a class="next" href="#slider-1">next</a>          
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `margin`? .....

Comment: @meine фото добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну например так

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 120;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #252525;
}

header li a {
  float: left;
  width: 98px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 14px 7px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font: normal 62.5% "proxima-nova-alt", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 5px;
  width: 10%;
}

header .logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes TMNT {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -1200px;
  }
}

a.prev,
a.next {
  height: 91px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 43px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
}

a.prev:hover,
a.next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  background: #000 url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JN1IZLtuToI/UUoZnMG3C_I/AAAAAAAAAE8/SEbJ9nqXGnY/s226/sprite.png') no-repeat -200px 25px;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  background: #000 url('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-JN1IZLtuToI/UUoZnMG3C_I/AAAAAAAAAE8/SEbJ9nqXGnY/s226/sprite.png') no-repeat -167px 25px;
}

.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide img {
  width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.slider .slide:target {
  z-index: 100;
}

.prefer .address {
  position: relative;
  z-index:99;
  background: #fff;
  width:80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Туристическая компания Юг-Вояж</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slider.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/YpUfTvW.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Туристам</a></li>
        <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li id="slider-1" class="slide">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PcDDGh9C6Uk/UUoRYu8TmGI/AAAAAAAAADk/bVCVnUEott4/s1231/2.jpeg.jpg">
        <a class="prev" href="#slider-4">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="#slider-2">next</a>
      </li>
      <li id="slider-2" class="slide">
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ImESS5vXwTQ/UUoRZtDDdwI/AAAAAAAAAD0/mBlvPxXMuDU/s1231/3.jpeg.jpg">
        <a class="prev" href="#slider-1">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="#slider-3">next</a>
      </li>
      <li id="slider-3" class="slide">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-a4HykmTjnLw/UUoRZ9AOzNI/AAAAAAAAAD8/bsVqg8naI2o/s1231/4.jpeg.jpg">
        <a class="prev" href="#slider-2">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="#slider-4">next</a>
      </li>
      <li id="slider-4" class="slide">
        <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-lmIWz4ADxc0/UUoRaFjdNXI/AAAAAAAAAEI/widPZMMiBVM/s1231/5.jpeg.jpg">
        <a class="prev" href="#slider-3">prev</a>
        <a class="next" href="#slider-1">next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="prefer">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="address">
        Какой-то длинный текст
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: класс Content я уже дальше сам описываю?

Comment: и еще проблема. запускаю локально у себя на компе. Эта нарисованная формочка двигает вверх слайдер, как бы сдавливая и не идет поверх слайдера. ЧТо не так? вроде тут все прям указано

Comment: z-index slide и следующему блоку добавьте, внесла в пример

Answer (score 0):

Первое организовываем через свойство `position: absolute` и в html заключить внутри родительского элемента.

Второе:

```
.logo img {width: 100% auto;}
```